# How should I fix this topology issue?

Tags: modeling, topology

I'm a beginner modeller, and I've been trying to create a revolver from a reference photo. I've been tweaking the topology here and there to make sure that I have no 3 or 5 vertex faces. However, when looking at the model with a subdivision surface modifier I get this weird pinched effect that you can see below[image][image: This is my model with my topology made visible]

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this? All answers are appreciated!

Comment: http://topologyguides.com

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you are hinting at but there is a pole where 6 edges come together which is not optimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if U look on Your 2nd picture there is a vertex related problem. As U wrote its important to have quad faces if possible but ALSO vertexes with 4 edges connected and U have 6 of them!

Try to repair the polyflow like on the picture below and everything will be fine ;).

[image: ]New loop of polygons needed[1]]

Answer (score 0):

If you are a begginer you should try less complex objects before try to create a revolver.
Look at YouTube for tutorials about booleans, crease, edge split, bevel and other hard surface tools.
To solve the problem you post try to use bevel modifier or add more loops (ctrl+R) near that junction.